# How to map an array of objects inside anather objects in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map a array of object inside another object in react. But there is an error `Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`.

```
const data={
comments: [{…}],
desc: "batman"
likes: ['001']
userid: "001"
username: "name"
}
```

```
 "This is what i have tried"

{data?.comments.map((val, id) => {
                return (
                    <div className='comment-section' key={id}>
                        <span style={{ color: 'gray' }}><b>{val.username}</b></span>
                        <span> {val.comment}</span>
                    </div>
                )

            })}
```

Comments is an array of objects containing username, comment fields in each object.

Comment: Your error means that `data.comments` is `undefined`, you should check that `data` is what you think it is and that it has a `comments` property. If `data` starts off as an empty object, then you should be using `data.comments?.map()`, if both data and comments can be `undefined` then you can add a `?` after data also.

Comment: *"Comments is an array of objects"* - The error tells otherwise.  Maybe `data` is being populated asynchronously somewhere and `comments` isn't available on this render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure, but in my case I put this

```
data?.comments && data?.comments?.map((val, id) => { 
....
....
}
```

This will render the map if `data.comments` is truthy

Comment: This could be simplified to be just `data?.comments?.map(...)`